# Doctrine entity manager and multiple threads updating database

Tags: php, concurrency, doctrine, symfony

I currently have an XHR request that can fire off N times from the client. This requests are handled by the server and each requests typically creates a new row in the database (all doctrine / xml).

Before I persist() the object, I make sure if has a unique filename (I am uploading assets) and I do this by overriding persist(), calling my getUniqueFilename() and then calling parent::persist.

I get a race condition when I perform multiple XHR requests w/the same filename. What happens if that multiple threads are running at the exact same time and checking the database for duplicates in order to generate the unique filename.

- Upload file
- Check database if filename exists
- Increment filename (eg: filename_1)

However, when multiple XHR requests occur in multiple threads a race condition occurs where multiple files are inserted into the database w/the same name (filename_1 is generated multiple times).

I think the way to solve this is either

- A mysql trigger
- Adding a unique constraint to the table for filename, and wrapping in try/catch in code

What would you do?

Comment: If the filenames need to be unique, I'd got for adding a constraint. Let the data-layer solve this. But anyhow, why do you have a `getUniqueFilename()` in the first place if it does such a "bad" job?

Comment: Good point - originally we never tested/thought about a user uploading assets w/the same filename in the same request (or the race condition that could occur). When testing this bug presented itself and I'm trying to determine the best way to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a unique constraint is the safest way to ensure consistent data. Anything at the PHP level could have some race conditions unless you have some other forms of locking, which will be less efficient.

You could also avoid the problem by making sure the file names become unique using other attributes such as the user it came from or keeping version history which would just make it look like there was a new version almost at the same time.

Comment: Yea, I think the unique constraint is a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: So I started implementing this and realized that the doctrine entity manager "shutsdown" when it throws an exception. So wrapping in a try/catch and attempting the persist() again doesn't work: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1037 - I'm back to the drawing board at this time.

Comment: Is a simple retry really supposed to work if unicity constraints fail?  Haveyou considered building your own unit of work?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm not very familiar w/the Symfony2 UoW - however, I will look into this. For now, we've tabled this issue in order to solve more pressing items, so I'm not marking any answer as accepted.When I revisit I will update my my selection. Thanks for everyones input.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a different strategy: Using the mysql auto_increment to get an id, saving the asset to the database, retrieving the id and then adding it to the filename. All the other ways have drawbacks where you have to perform partial rollbacks, handle dublicated filenames etc.

I would also suggest to not use the original filename for storing the object: You run into troubles with forbidden characters on different operating systems as well as character encoding, possible dublicates for some reason (e.g. because the database is case_sensitive where the file system is not). There may be other drawbacks like max file name length or so which you might not be aware of right now.

My solution is simply using a mysql auto increment as filename. If you think about it it makes sense. The auto increment is used as a unique idenfitier. If you make sure to only story objects from one table into one folder, you have no problems with identifieng different assets, filenames etc.

If you insist on keeping your way, you could make the filename unique in the database and then restart on a failing flush as you suggested.

Comment: Interesting, your first paragraph is a good solution too. I'm going to ponder for a bit before I implement anything. Thanks Boo.

Comment: Yeah, you should play around a bit and see if this works for you. I had many problems with file uploads and issues stated above, so now I will always use some kind of id which I generate as filename and never ever use the original filename. If you need the filename for the url or so, you can always use some kind of controller which looks up the name on the filesystem and then load the correct asset. Most issues can be resolved while working around the little flawes that come with using the original filenames are hard to handle especially as they come up unannounced.

Comment: I currently have assorted code that works w/the filename/filepath, so I have sort of conform to the existing internal API. After re-reading your answer a few times and thinking about, I'm not sure it will work in this case - though it's a good idea and would probably work well in other cases. I may make the filename field a constraint and fail on that in code ...